# Javascript and Images in Visualforce rendered as Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, salesforce, visualforce

I have this VF renderd as Word:

`<apex:page controller="MacchinePDFController" language="it_IT" cache="true" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" sidebar="false" contentType="application/msword#{!wordTitle}.doc">`

```
<apex:repeat value="{!imagesURLs}" var="attach" id="theImgRepeat">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
             <img src="{!attach}" id="{!attach}" width="{!sizesByURL[attach].width}" height="{!sizesByURL[attach].height}" style="display:block;" /><br/><!--onload="resize()" -->
        </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

And this controller

```
if (!contentDistributionList.isEmpty()) {
      imagesURLs = new List<String>();
      sizesByURL = new Map<String, SizeWrapper>();
      theFirstImage = contentDistributionList[0].ContentDownloadUrl;
      for (ContentDistribution cd : contentDistributionList) {
              sizesByURL.put(cd.ContentDownloadUrl, new SizeWrapper(versionsById.get(cd.ContentVersionId).Height__c, versionsById.get(cd.ContentVersionId).Width__c));
              imageResize.imageResize(imagesURLs);
      }
}
```

I need to dynamically resize the images to fit every page before downloading the word document. Fields Height__c and Width__c are always null - won't never be populated.

Is there anyway to achieve this with JS? I've tried numerous times but it seems js doesn't even log a console.log instruction. Are we sure that contentType="application/msword#{!wordTitle}.doc" works with JS?

Thanks

Comment: Visualforce does not render as Word. It renders as HTML, which Word is in some situations willing to accept as if it were a Word document. You are completely at the mercy of Word's rendering engine, and can test its capabilities just by creating an HTML file, naming it ".doc" and opening it in Word.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but do you think is there any way a js function could do the job?

Comment: I doubt it but I cannot say that I've tried it myself.